# How to lodge tracking event for Customer using Kustomer API

Tags: kustomer

I am trying to integrate Kustomer with a service of mine using their APIs. I am successfully able to create Customer Objects Using their Customer Create API.

Now I want to lodge tracking events for a particular Customer, also I want to control to which session I want to lodge the event using `sessionId`. Currently I with respect to their API reference [Kustomer Event Tracking API](https://developer.kustomer.com/kustomer-api-docs/reference/tracking-events#createatrackingevent) I am confused about how to exactly link a tracking event to a Customer and how to exactly use the `trackingId` and `sessionId` for successful integration.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to track and manage here, it may make more sense to leverage custom attributes or kobjects attached to the customer record.  Feel free to reach out to us at support@kustomer.com, and we would be happy to review your particular use case further and advise on an appropriate solution.

Best Regards,

Lucas